# .delegate equivalent of an existing .hover method in jQuery 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, event-handling, hover, delegates

I have an event handler bound to the hover event using the .hover method, which is below:

```
$(".nav li").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

It is important to note, that I require both functions within the handler to ensure synchronisation. Is it possible to rewrite the function using .delegate, as the following does not work?

```
$(".nav").delegate("li", "hover", function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
$(".nav").delegate("li", "hover", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

This depends on `.nav` not getting replaced via AJAX or otherwise though, since that's where the event handler lives.  If it is being replaced, you have to attach the delegate on a higher ancestor that's *not* getting replaced.

Also a minor correction, `$(".nav li").hover(function () {` isn't using the `.live()` method, that would be: `$(".nav li").live('hover', function () {`.  `.hover()` binds the event directly to the element when that code runs...any future elements wouldn't trigger that hover code, that's where `.live()` and `.delegate()` differ, they work on future elements via bubbling.

Comment: Very embarrassed. Blindly assumed I was converting a .live method instead of a .hover method, eyes evidently not focusing properly today. So +1 for that.

With respect to attaching to a parent that is at risk of being programmatically replaced. I hadn't realised the restriction and have been attaching to parents that don't necessarily exist at the time of binding with no problem.

Comment: @kim3er - With your current method, they must exist at the time of the binding, otherwise the selector would find/bind nothing :)  If your current method works, the delegate method I posted should as well, give it a shot, let me know if you have other problems.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the .delegate method, not .hover in that last sentence.

Comment: And again you are correct. .delegate methods need to be attached to a static element, which makes perfect sense when you think about it. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: With respect to the original question. I will be keeping the .hover method as there doesn't appear to be a direct replacement using .delegate at the moment.

Comment: @kim3er - Correct, there's no direct replacement, and if it works no reason breaking it :)

Answer (score 1):

To add/remove a class Nick's solution is perfect as jQuery provides the appropriate toggleClass method.

If you need to trigger more complex functions that do not have a corresponding toggle method available, you can do that by testing the event type:

```
$(".nav").delegate("li", "hover", function (event) {
if(event.type == "mouseenter"){
    $(this).find(".subDiv").slideDown();
}else{
    $(this).find(".subDiv").slideUp();
}
});
```

This will work for jQuery >=1.4.3 - for older versions use *mouseover* instead of *mouseenter*.