# Using delegate() with hover()?

Tags: jquery

I have a ul element with many li items:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

when the user hovers their mouse over an li element, I'd like show some hidden buttons on the li, when they stop hovering, hide the buttons again. Trying to use delegate:

```
$("#myList").delegate("li", "hover", function () {
    if (iAmHovered()) {
        showButtons();
    } else {
        hideButtons();
    }
});
```

the above gets called for both hover and 'un-hover'. How can I distinguish if it's a leave or enter though?

Also, I got this sample from this question:
[.delegate equivalent of an existing .hover method in jQuery 1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591885/delegate-equivalent-of-an-existing-hover-method-in-jquery-1-4-2)

in which Nick says:

> This depends on [#myList] not getting replaced via AJAX or otherwise though, since that's where the event handler lives.

I do replace the contents of #myList though, using:

```
$("#myList").empty();
```

will that cause a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to test for the type of event, like this:

```
$("#myList").delegate("li", "hover", function ( event ) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        showButtons();
    } else {
        hideButtons();
    }
});
```

Since there's only one handler to run for *both* events, we are checking to see which one fired, and running the appropriate code.

As opposed to *binding* `hover` directly to the element where it is able to accept two handlers for the two event types.

---

**EDIT:** Note that as of `jQuery 1.4.3`, the type of event that is reported when using `'hover'` with `.delegate()` or `.live()` is no longer `mouseover/mouseout` (as it ought to be). Now it will be `mouseenter/mouseleave`, which just seems silly since they're non-bubbling events.

So the `if()` statement would look like:

```
if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the handler function so that it pays attention to the event argument, and then check the type.