# delegate/on with hover

Tags: jquery, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using delegate() with hover()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367769/using-delegate-with-hover)

I am trying this code, but apparently I am doing something wrong. With this code the `hover` effect doesn't work.

However something like : `$('.group>span').hover (function() {` works well but I need to delegate the `html()` content.

```
<div class="group">
    <span></span>
</div>

$('.group>span').delegate("hover", "a", function() {
    $(this).html('<a href="#new_list">Some button</a>');
}, function() {
    $(this).empty();
});​
```

Any idea? thanks

Comment: I updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10081842/601179). you use the delegate function wrong

Comment: You're not expecting any hover events on `<a>`, correct?

Comment: i am doing some tests, but yes, i will accept, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of arguments you pass to the `delegate` is invalid. You pass **4** while it should take only 3.

`.delegate( selector, eventType, handler(eventObject) )` is the function signature.
**And the order of the parameters in your code is wrong! you swapped the selector and the event type**

You wrote this:

```
$('.group>span').delegate ("hover", "a", function() {
```

While it should be in this order:

```
$('.group>span').delegate ("a", "hover", function() {
```

Anyway you can use `delegate` for `hover` this way :

```
$('.group>span').delegate("a", "mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).html('<a href="#new_list">Some button</a>');
});

$('.group>span').delegate("a", "mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).empty();
}​);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NSYWG/1/)
You can see another way to go in this question:
[Using delegate() with hover()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367769/using-delegate-with-hover)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NSYWG/ -> something wrong?

Comment: @loops. Yes... Updated your fiddle. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NSYWG/1/)

Comment: **@Downvoter please explain your actions!!!**

Answer (score 0):

[`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is just a convenience wrapper around `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. I think you will have to handle each separately.

Comment: While you're right. there are more errors in his code... :)